# I am getting error while using fedex test tracking number

Tags: java, fedex

I'm configuring FEDEX shipping in Custom application. I got test account number, password, api key and meter number by logging in to a test FEDEX account. Looks like everything fine. But I am getting error message using test A/c No `1111111111111` or `123456789012` or `794813378033`

Can anybody help with this?

Error Message:

```
Configuration file read-only so engine configuration changes will not be saved.
Notifications:
  Notification no. 0: 
    Severity: ERROR
    Code: 9040
    Message: No information for the following shipments has been received by our system yet.  Please try again or contact Customer Service at 1.800.Go.FedEx(R) 800.463.3339.
    Source: trck
  Notification no. 1: 
    Severity: WARNING
    Code: 30035
    Message: We are unable to provide notifications because either the package is too old or there is more than one package with the provided tracking number.
    Source: trck
```

Comment: "We are unable to provide notifications because either the package is too old or there is more than one package with the provided tracking number."  Use a real tracking number.  I'm sure your company can scrounge up one tracking number.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide ship functionality as well try get it to work first. Ship response should carry a valid tracking no which you can use for testing your tracking functionality!